# GIT tracks changes occurred BEFORE it was installed

Tags: eclipse, git

Maybe I have hallucinations, but I'm pretty sure of what I'm saying (I am new to GIT): I have some java code on my local drive, never versioned (to any versioning system, neither GIT nor SVN or whatever). I've created a repository on bitbucket, then I imported the source code from local drive. I did some testing, following a tutorial. Everything worked fine since I've noticed that, in the history folder (I am using the Eclipse plugin) I could diff two older versions of a file (and have the correct diff displayed), but these changes were made BEFORE I even created the git repository (local and remote).

I cancompare two versions saved yesterday:

I![YESTERDAY][1]

I can compare two more recent versions (today):

![TODAY][2]

-- I cannot post images, not enough reputation :( --

Notice that I installed GIT (and created the bitbucket repository) TODAY!

Comment: Were you using some kind of IDE to construct the code?  Sometimes they are sneakily using version control behind the scenes without really telling you.  You should look in the `git log` output for the dates of previous commits.

Comment: I use Eclipse. I installed the egit plug-in after having installed the GIT client. The command-line "> git log "only gives me today's commit history (as I expected). I strongly suspect that this is due to Eclipse, as you pointed out

Comment: My first thought was a local time vs. UTC issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Eclipse tracking the history. I have a toy Java project open in Eclipse—which has not been commited to any source control—and I am able to diff against previous versions I saved yesterday.

To see for yourself:

1. Create a new Java project
2. Create a new class file
3. Make several changes, saving each time
4. Compare with > Local history...

Comment: Yes, finally I realized that only Eclipse could be the guilty, also because I could diff 'versions' of the same file related to plain 'save' actions (and not 'commit' or 'push'). I couldn't guess where this information is stored, I took a look under the .metadata/ folder but I couldn't find any.